# Camel routing set a variable

Tags: java, routes, apache-camel

I'd like to set a variable in a camel-routing. 
for example: `SomethingBlaBla.when(header("msgType").contains("No Doc.")).setVariableWhichCanGetAccessedFromOutside`

Is it possible to set a variable in the routing? Because when `msgType` contains `"No Doc"` than I'd like to set a counter-variable to 500. In an other class it should be possible to access this variable and get the value out of it.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can configure [camel processor](http://camel.apache.org/processor.html) to achieve this.

Comment: Yes a processor a a regular java bean, allows you to do whatever you want.